# Using g++ to compile and link program with header cpp files in subfolder

Tags: c++, linux, g++, undefined-reference

Very new to this C++ thing and have been trying all night to compile a basic program with header files in a subfolder - I must be something so stupid but easily fixed. Maybe my lack of understanding around namespaces - or how headers are included???

Hopefully someone can help me out

All the examples seem to say I can compile / link on one line or in separate steps - the separate steps seems to give me the least number of errors

I can get the cpp files to compile and create .o files but can't get the output file to be created.

**Final try:**  `g++ ProcessCAP.o ./network/SocketClient.o -o ProcessCAP`

**Error message:**
`./network/SocketClient.o:(.rodata+0xc0): undefined reference to 'CAP::SocketClient::send(std::string)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

**Main Program:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include "network/SocketClient.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace CAP;

//int argc, char *argv[]

int main(void){

    cout << "Starting CAP Processor Example" << "\n";
    SocketClient sc("streaming1.my-url.com", 8080);
    sc.connectToServer();

    string rec = sc.receive(4096);
    while (rec.length() > 0) {
        cout << "Received [" << rec << "] \n";
        string rec = sc.receive(4096);
    }

    sc.disconnectFromServer();
    cout << "End of CAP Processor Example" << "\n";
}
```

***Files in the "network" subfolder:***

**SocketClient.cpp**

```
#include "SocketClient.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

namespace CAP {

SocketClient::SocketClient(std::string serverName, int portNumber) {
    this->socketfd = -1;
    this->server = NULL;
    this->serverName = serverName;
    this->portNumber = portNumber;
    this->isConnected = false;
}

int SocketClient::connectToServer(){

    socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socketfd < 0){
        perror("Socket Client: error opening socket.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    server = gethostbyname(serverName.data());
    if (server == NULL) {
        perror("Socket Client: error - no such host.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    bzero((char *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(portNumber);

    if (connect(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0){
        perror("Socket Client: error connecting to the server.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    this->isConnected = true;
    return 0;
}

string SocketClient::receive(int size=4096){
    char readBuffer[size];
    int n = read(this->socketfd, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));
    if (n < 0){
       perror("Socket Client: error reading from socket");
    }
    return string(readBuffer);
}

int SocketClient::disconnectFromServer(){
    this->isConnected = false;
    close(this->socketfd);
    return 0;
}

SocketClient::~SocketClient() {
    if (this->isConnected == true){
        disconnectFromServer();
    }
}

} /* namespace CAP */
```

**SocketClient.h** (also in network subfolder)

```
#ifndef SOCKETCLIENT_H_
#define SOCKETCLIENT_H_

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string>

namespace CAP {

class SocketClient {

private:
    int         socketfd;
    struct      sockaddr_in   serverAddress;
    struct      hostent       *server;
    std::string serverName;
    int         portNumber;
    bool        isConnected;

public:
    SocketClient(std::string serverName, int portNumber);
    virtual int connectToServer();
    virtual int disconnectFromServer();
    virtual int send(std::string message);
    virtual std::string receive(int size);
    bool isClientConnected() { return this->isConnected; }
    virtual ~SocketClient();
};

}

#endif /* SOCKETCLIENT_H_ */
```

Comment: You would get the same error if you collected all the source code in one file. You have declared `send`, but not implemented it. In general, one good way to attack problems of the kind huh-this-is-not-what-i-expected, is to try to reproduce the problem in an as simple as possible example.

Comment: In other news, you run some chance of inadvertent text substitution with the name CAP. You can avoid that by reserving SHOUTCASE names for macros.

Comment: Also, in the implementation file you can avoid implementing a function with the wrong signature, or one that isn't declared, by using the form `void ns::foo() {}` instead of `namespace ns{ void foo() {} }`.

Comment: Thank you @Alf - it seems so obvious now. The function was implemented but I removed it as my system was only going to receive data. Noted your case suggestion. It's going to be a long road ahead for me.